# Decode Characters Pandas

Tags: python, regex, pandas

Below is a sample of my DF

```
ROLE                        NAME
GESELLSCHAFTER              DUPONT DUPONT
GESCHÃ¤FTSFÃ¼HRER           DUPONT DUPONT
KOMPLEMENTÃ¤R               DUPONT DUPONT
GESELLSCHAFTER              DUPONT DUPONT
KOMPLEMENTÃ¤R               DUPONT DUPONT
```

The aim would be to fix the special characters. 
For eg, 'KOMPLEMENTÃ¤R'--> should be 'KOMPLEMENTAR' (with or without the Accent doesn't really matter)

Thus, I tried to construct a list and replace the value name by the below dic list.

```
{'A¤':'A', 'A–':'A', 'A¶':'A', 'A€':'A', 'Aƒ':'A', 'A„':'A', 'A\…':'A', 'A¡':'A', 
'A¢':'A', 'A£':'A', 'A¥':'A', 'A¦':'A', 
'A©':'E', 'Aˆ':'E', 'A‰':'E', 'AŠ':'E', 'A‹':'E', 
'AŒ':'I', 'AŽ':'I', 'A¬':'I', 'A­':'I', 'A®':'I', 'A¯':'I',
'A“':'O', 'A”':'O', 'A•':'O', 'A–':'O', 'A°':'O', 'A²':'O', 'A³':'O', 'A´':'O', 'Aµ':'O', 'A¶':'O',
 'A¼':'U', 'A™':'U', 'Aš':'U', 'Aœ':'U', 'A¹':'U', 'Aº':'U', 'A»':'U', 'Ã¿':'U'}

for key, value in dic.items():
        df['ROLE'] = df['ROLE'].str.replace(key, value)
```

However, I was wondering if there is a better way of dealing with this issue using regular expression perhaps?

Below is a solution found when printing.

```
nfd_example = 'KOMPLEMENTÃ¤R'
print(nfd_example.encode('cp1252').decode('utf-8-sig'))
output
KOMPLEMENTäR
```

Besides, when I try the same code on Pandas column, here is the output error:

```
df['ROLE_decode'] = df['ROLE'].str.encode('cp1252').str.decode('utf-8-sig')
'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xc4 in position 6: invalid continuation byte
```

> 

### EDIT

Below is list of Unique Values from Role Column

```
AKTIONÃ¤R                                 133
AKTIONÄR                                   11
AUFSICHTSRAT                              450
AUSÃ¼BENDE PERSON                         688
AUSÜBENDE PERSON                          131
DEFAULT KEY                                62
GESCHÃ¤FTSFÃ¼HRENDER DIREKTOR               2
GESCHÃ¤FTSFÃ¼HRER                        9555
```

When Using the below code

```
df['ROLE_decode'] = df['ROLE'].str.encode('cp1252').str.decode('utf-8-sig', 'ignore').apply(unidecode)
```

It gives me the below Unique Values

```
AKTIONR                                   11
AKTIONaR                                 133
AUFSICHTSRAT                             450
AUSBENDE PERSON                          131
AUSuBENDE PERSON                         688
DEFAULT KEY                               62
GESCHFTSFHRER                            797
GESCHaFTSFuHRENDER DIREKTOR                2
GESCHaFTSFuHRER                         9555
```

So, if anyone has an idea, thanks for your help!

Comment: How did this broken data get into the dataframe in the first place? Would it be possible to fix it at that stage?

Comment: @ Ture Pålsson The data has been extracted like that from an XML doc. Thus, I have received a csv file as shown within the sample

Comment: I firmly believe that this sort of issue is best fixed as close to the source as possible. If the CSV file has broken encoding, then I would try to get whoever provided the CSV file to fix that. Admittedly, this is sometimes not possible, usually for political reasons.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass `regex=True` to `replace`:

```
# the included dic seems to have `A` instead of 'Ã'
dic ={'Ã¼':'U', 'Ã¤':'A'}

df['ROLE'] = df['ROLE'].replace(dic, regex=True)
```

Output:

```
              ROLE           NAME
0   GESELLSCHAFTER  DUPONT DUPONT
1  GESCHAFTSFUHRER  DUPONT DUPONT
2     KOMPLEMENTAR  DUPONT DUPONT
3   GESELLSCHAFTER  DUPONT DUPONT
4     KOMPLEMENTAR  DUPONT DUPONT
```

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. However, as mentionned, I'd like to use a solution more 'cleaner'. Otherwise, I would have to check all special characters and replace them manually

Answer (score 0):

This solution is quite long and might not work well on a large dataset, first decompose using `unicodedata` then encode to `ascii` to remove the accents and decode to `utf-8`

```
from unicodedata import normalize
df.ROLE.apply(lambda x: normalize('NFD', x).encode(
    'ascii', 'ignore').decode('utf-8-sig'))

# 0                       AKTIONAR
# 1                       AKTIONAR
# 2                   AUFSICHTSRAT
# 3               AUSABENDE PERSON
# 4               AUSUBENDE PERSON
# 5                    DEFAULT KEY
# 6    GESCHAFTSFAHRENDER DIREKTOR
# 7                GESCHAFTSFAHRER
# Name: ROLE, dtype: object
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution. I have edited the question with your remarks

Comment: Are you still looking for a different solution?

Comment: it shouldn't  give AKTIONR and AKTIONaR because both of them are similar. Using the provided code, it skips letter A (because it has an accent perhaps?)