# remove character encoding in panda column

Tags: pandas, decode

I have the following data in my csv, how do I decode it?

| col |
| --- |
| b'Loader Crane 100 tm WIP' |
| b'2022 New model Honda Race' |
| b'Volkswagen Samba Bus' |
| b'Automated Pneumatic Filli' |
| b'Kenworth T401 1998' |

the following code returns

```
with open(file_grab_cad, 'rb') as rawdata:
    result = chardet.detect(rawdata.read(100000))

# check what the character encoding might be
print(result)
{'encoding': 'ascii', 'confidence': 1.0, 'language': ''}
```

the following line makes the col all NaN

```
df.col.decode('ascii')
```

Reading with encoding enabled also dont help, I have tried all types of encodings such, cp1252, utf-8, ascii, etc.

```
pd.read_csv(encoding="cp1252")
```

solution presented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61680599/decode-characters-pandas) is also not helpful. Please help.

Comment: `b'Loader Crane 100 tm WIP'` suggest binary strings. Maybe you shouldn't have exported the data to csv at the first place.

Comment: any suggestions what to do about it?

Comment: Use to_pickle and read_pickle to save and load instead.

Comment: Your [mcve] seems to be a bit unclear. Please elaborate…